# OneNote 2010 bullet indenting

Tags: microsoft-office, microsoft-onenote-2010, microsoft-onenote-2007

In OneNote 2007, when you typed a dash and pressed space, you'd get a bulleted list. The same thing happens in 2010, except it indents the bullets over. I find this very annoying and have not been able to figure out how to turn it off. When working on old notebooks from OneNote 2007, the old paradigm is used, but not on new notebooks from 2010. Is there a way to revert the behavior back to the way it was in OneNote 2007? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

If you wish to disable auto bullets & numbering permanently, click Tools -> Options -> Editing and remove the checkmark from Apply numbering/bullets to lists automatically.

This is a direct paste from [Link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/onenotetips/outlining-in-onenote)